# Reply to message by email

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

I want my users to be able to reply to my... let's call it *forum*, via email. When something gets posted to a topic they're watching, they get an email. I want them to be able to reply to that email and have my script post a message in the topic as that user.

My forum is written in PHP + Zend and my email provider is Google Apps for Businesses (so GMail).

Is there any way I can fetch all emails sent to a particular address and parse them in PHP (or Python or something else for that matter, as long as it's not C)?

Comment: Just google PHP + IMAP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.read.html

Comment: @TimFountain Amazing, didn't know Zend Framework had such a thing :D Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out.

http://code.google.com/p/php-imap/

You can pretty easily set up an environment that accepts the emails and will let you create a script to handle the information and put it in the db manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can connect with IMAP or POP to gmail and fetch emails.